# Is there a keyboard shortcut to toggle text size in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

IE 6+ had the capability to hold **ctrl** + **mousewheel** to increase and decrease the text size on the page.  However, now IE 8 has replaced that functionality with the widely accepted full page zoom +-.  Has anyone found a keyboard shortcut that will just increase and decrease the text size again?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't exactly a *shortcut*, but it can be accomplished from the keyboard.

- <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> will bring up the View menu
- <kbd>x</kbd> will bring up the Text size submenu
- <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>down</kbd> arrow keys choose the size
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> selects.

This works even if the menu bar isn't visible.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but hoping for something with far less keypresses.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure that's all you've got if you don't like the snazzy "full-page zoom" bug, er... I mean, feature.

Answer (score 1):

Zoom:

To increase:

**<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>**

and

To decrease

**<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>**

Text size:

**<kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>**

**<kbd>x</kbd>**

**<kbd>g</kbd>** or **<kbd>l</kbd>** or **<kbd>m</kbd>** or **<kbd>s</kbd>** or **<kbd>a</kbd>**

Comment: You just did the same thing I did.  This does not work in IE8... like he says... in the question.

Comment: I added keys to change the text size now, I jumped the gun before ;)